# Tricky Interview Question

Tags: regression, neural-networks, classification

I was recently given an interview, and given the following scenario:

You have one classification problem to solve. You can use either of the following 
1) linear regression algorithm 
2) Neural Network with linear activation function

Which would give me the better answer for this type of question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! You might have some more success if you updated your question to add the answer you gave, or the thoughts that you've had so far as you tried to answer the question.

Comment: You need to go somewhere: would you take train or a bus? Also, neither of those is a classification algorithm.

Comment: Why is this tricky? Define the metric for "ideal"?

Comment: Non-statistical question at root:  Pretty obviously, this 'question' gives you an opportunity to show you know what (1) and (2) are, and to mention criteria for choosing one or the other. If you want the job, probably not the best idea to say that's a really stupid question without more information.

Comment: This probably requires the self-study algorithm.

Comment: The question requires more detail about the "classification" problem to make it understandable.

Comment: If that was the whole question, the answer may be to find a new job.

Comment: Thanks for replying guys , as interviewers clearly mentioned that non of the method is suitable but if you don't have any choice what you will do ? May be they were asking for alternative options like somehow convert classification data into regression and then use given method ...

Answer (score 1):

This question is testing you when to use neural network and when to use regression.

Since it is a classification problem, the first you should know is that linear regression (not logistic) is a REGRESSION, not a classification algorithm. Then the answer should be obvious, Neural Network. BUT, there is a trap, you shouldn't use a `linear activation function`, the reason why the neural networks can have many layers is that they are using non-linear activation function. If using linear ones, the whole neural network will collapse into only a 'huge' linear function.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, this is a tricky question because, clearly, neither method is well suited for the task. Giving them the benefit of the doubt, I assume that they know this, and they know that you know this. So the "trick" is, basically, with a gun to your head and being forced to pick between two bad options, knowing what you know about those options, *which one is less bad*?

Given this circumstance, I would choose the Neural Network with linear activation for the following reason:

A NN is a universal function approximator. The function you want to approximate is one that *either* outputs a real number between $0$ and $1$, or only outputs $0$ or $1$ (or only outputs an upper-bounded positive integer, if this is a multi-class classification).

For example, if the *true* distribution of the data is the Sigmoid of a linear combination of the inputs (the form of an ordinary logistic regression), it is possible, in principle, for a neural network with linear activation to mimic this, given enough input data and network complexity. But it is *impossible* for an ordinary linear regression to mimic this. (Though, keep in mind, that a NN with linear activation outputting a number between $0$ and $1$ wouldn't have the same interpretation as a logistic model doing this, because a linear model's loss function is trained to minimize the difference between its direct output and the target variables in the data, *not* to estimate the probability that the target will be a certain value. This is still an inherent flaw in the method, as it's not meant to handle Bernoulli-distributed data.)

With that said, I think it would be important, in an interview, for you to clarify that you know that this is the better of two bad options. Make sure you understand that it is not actually a viable choice in a real scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As Bill Chen mentioned, a neural network that only uses linear activation functions *is* a linear regression. So the answer here is that this is a choice between 1) linear regression and 2) linear regression which is not really a choice and linear regression is not suitable for classification.

Comment: To clarify this post, if the activation functions in the hidden layers as well as the final layer are all linear functions, then the neural net is a linear regression. I took the question to mean, however, that the hidden layers do normal neural net activations (ReLU, etc) with the output neuron having a linear activation function, which makes the regression nonlinear.